# Random output when receiving data from SFML socket

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, sfml

When running this code I am receiving completely random output when entering 'C' and nothing happening when entering 'S'.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>

int main()
{
sf::IpAddress ip = sf::IpAddress::getLocalAddress();
sf::TcpSocket socket;
char connectionType, buffer[2000];
std::size_t received;

std::cout << "C for client, S for server" << std::endl;
std::cin >> connectionType;

std::string packetText = "test";

if (connectionType == 'S')
{
    sf::TcpListener listener;
    listener.listen(2000);
    listener.accept(socket);
}
else if (connectionType == 'C')
{
    socket.connect(ip, 2000);
}

socket.send(packetText.c_str(), packetText.length() + 1);
socket.receive(buffer, sizeof(buffer), received);
std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
system("pause");
}
```

[random output when entering C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sC8YR.png)

Comment: Silly question, but are you starting the server first, then starting a client? This [works for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhCzE.gif).

Comment: Thanks! Starting the server first fixed it!

Comment: Cool! You might want to handle that as an error. What is going on is the `connect()`, `send()`, and `receive()` are all failing but you aren't checking the return values. Additionally, you might want to zero out `received` and check that you actually received something before printing using the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to handle that as an error. What is going on is the `connect()`, `send()`, and `receive()` are all failing but you aren't checking the return values. Additionally, you might want to zero out `received` and check that you actually received something before printing using the buffer.
                    – Sean Cline